# USB to LAN adapter not recognized on boot

Tags: usb

I bought a cheap VK-QF9700 to connect to my new Raspberry PI Zero.
I know the chipset (DM9601) had some problems with the Raspbian kernel that has been recently updated.

The problem I have is that if I power on the Raspberry, wait for the boot to finish and then plug the Ethernet adapter in the Micro USB, everything works fine.

But if I leave the adapter plugged in and try to boot, the adapter does not get recognized.

I run `lsusb` in `rc.local` to check if it is detected, but the command just shows me the standard USB Hub without any devices attached.

I tried resetting (with a utility I found around, `usbreset`) the USB hub, but nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have a similar problem with other usb devices on my Pi Zero, it only seems to happen when I use certain otg adapters.

Comment: Thank you Patrick. Did you manage to fix it in any way? I don't use any adapter,I directly attach the USB Ethernet device to the micro USB of the raspberry. Marco

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with my usb ethernet adapter but I solved it in my case by removing the settings used to connect the pi over usb to my laptop.

These settings are not default however and I added these myself before.

So for raspbian Jessie this is:

1. Go into your boot partition, it is automaticly mounted at `/boot/`
2. From `config.txt` remove `dtoverlay=dwc2`
3. From `cmdline.txt` remove `modules_load=dwc2,g_ether`

For me this solved the problem and after a reboot ethernet directly showed up. However you cannot ssh into the pi anymore using usb, which seem unneccessary anyway because you have an ethernet now.

Answer (score 0):

See my post: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=334055 and my reply.
I have the same problem with different USB to network adapters (UGREEN / BELKIN), but in my case it only is a problem when booting from an USB
SSD. The Belkin adapter should work out of the box conform the rpi compatibilty list.

When I boot from SD-card no problems. You can check it with the `dmesg` command.